# Flutter: Bottom sheet with TextField/TextFormField

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, textfield, bottom-sheet

In part of our application, I would like to have a simple form in `BottomSheet` like with the below code. unfortunately when i put into that, I get an error

> The following assertion was thrown during performLayout(): An
> InputDecorator, which is typically created by a TextField, cannot have
> an unbounded width. This happens when the parent widget does not
> provide a finite width constraint. For example, if the InputDecorator
> is contained by a Row, then its width must be constrained. An Expanded
> widget or a SizedBox can be used to constrain the width of the
> InputDecorator or the TextField that contains it.
> 'package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart': Failed assertion:
> line 881 pos 7: 'layoutConstraints.maxWidth < double.infinity'

my implemented code:

```
  void _settingModalBottomSheet(context){
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        elevation: 8.0,
        builder: (BuildContext bc){
          return Directionality(
            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                minHeight: 250.0
              ),
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0,10.0,0.0,10.0),
                child: new Wrap(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'please fill this form',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 13.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Divider(),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text('item 1'),
                            Container(
                              child: TextField(),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text('item 2'),
                            Container(
                              child: TextField(),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),

                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You will have to provide a specific width to the `TextField`, simply provide `width` in your `Container` or wrap your `Column` in  `Expanded`.

Solution 1

```
Container(
  width: 100, // do it in both Container
  child: TextField(),
),
```

---

Solution 2

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded( // wrap your Column in Expanded
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('item 1'),
          Container(child: TextField()),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Expanded( // wrap your Column in Expanded
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('item 2'),
          Container(child: TextField()),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap TextField inside Container.

```
 Container(
   width: 100,
   child: TextField()
 ),
```

Answer (score -5):

Wrap your `TextField` in a column with a specified height.

```
Column(
  width: 100,
  child: TextField()
),
```

Comment: Sorry, this won't help, the user isn't asking to limit the height of `TextField`.